# Custom matplotlib style import error

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've created my own mplstyle, and I would like to import it using the standard way

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt    
plt.style.use(path_to_file/name_of_file.mplstyle)
```

This is the contents of the file:

```
_internal.classic_mode : False
agg.path.chunksize : 0
animation.avconv_args : []
animation.avconv_path : avconv
animation.bitrate : -1
animation.codec : h264
animation.convert_args : []
animation.convert_path : convert
animation.embed_limit : 20.0
animation.ffmpeg_args : []
animation.ffmpeg_path : ffmpeg
animation.frame_format : png
animation.html : none
animation.html_args : []
animation.writer : ffmpeg
axes.autolimit_mode : data
axes.axisbelow : True
axes.edgecolor : .15
axes.facecolor : white
axes.formatter.limits : -7, 7
axes.formatter.min_exponent : 0
axes.formatter.offset_threshold : 4
axes.formatter.use_locale : False
axes.formatter.use_mathtext : False
axes.formatter.useoffset : True
axes.grid : True
axes.grid.axis : both
axes.grid.which : major
axes.labelcolor : .15
axes.labelpad : 4.0
axes.labelsize : medium
axes.labelweight : normal
axes.linewidth : 1.0
axes.prop_cycle : cycler('color', ['1f77b4', 'ff7f0e', '2ca02c', 'd62728', '9467bd', '8c564b', 'e377c2', '7f7f7f', 'bcbd22', '17becf'])
axes.spines.bottom : True
axes.spines.left : True
axes.spines.right : True
axes.spines.top : True
axes.titlepad : 6.0
axes.titlesize : large
axes.titleweight : normal
axes.unicode_minus : True
axes.xmargin : 0.05
axes.ymargin : 0.05
axes3d.grid : True
backend.qt5 : PyQt5
boxplot.bootstrap : None
boxplot.boxprops.color : k
boxplot.boxprops.linestyle : -
boxplot.boxprops.linewidth : 1.0
boxplot.capprops.color : k
boxplot.capprops.linestyle : -
boxplot.capprops.linewidth : 1.0
boxplot.flierprops.color : k
boxplot.flierprops.linestyle : none
boxplot.flierprops.linewidth : 1.0
boxplot.flierprops.marker : o
boxplot.flierprops.markeredgecolor : k
boxplot.flierprops.markerfacecolor : none
boxplot.flierprops.markersize : 6.0
boxplot.meanline : False
boxplot.meanprops.color : C2
boxplot.meanprops.linestyle : --
boxplot.meanprops.linewidth : 1.0
boxplot.meanprops.marker : ^
boxplot.meanprops.markeredgecolor : C2
boxplot.meanprops.markerfacecolor : C2
boxplot.meanprops.markersize : 6.0
boxplot.medianprops.color : C1
boxplot.medianprops.linestyle : -
boxplot.medianprops.linewidth : 1.0
boxplot.notch : False
boxplot.patchartist : False
boxplot.showbox : True
boxplot.showcaps : True
boxplot.showfliers : True
boxplot.showmeans : False
boxplot.vertical : True
boxplot.whiskerprops.color : k
boxplot.whiskerprops.linestyle : -
boxplot.whiskerprops.linewidth : 1.0
boxplot.whiskers : 1.5
contour.corner_mask : True
contour.negative_linestyle : dashed
date.autoformatter.day : %Y-%m-%d
date.autoformatter.hour : %m-%d %H
date.autoformatter.microsecond : %M:%S.%f
date.autoformatter.minute : %d %H:%M
date.autoformatter.month : %Y-%m
date.autoformatter.second : %H:%M:%S
date.autoformatter.year : %Y
errorbar.capsize : 0.0
examples.directory :
figure.autolayout : False
figure.dpi : 72.0
figure.edgecolor : 1, 1, 1, 0
figure.facecolor : 1, 1, 1, 0
figure.figsize : 6.0, 4.0
figure.frameon : True
figure.subplot.bottom : 0.125
figure.subplot.hspace : 0.2
figure.subplot.left : 0.125
figure.subplot.right : 0.9
figure.subplot.top : 0.88
figure.subplot.wspace : 0.2
figure.titlesize : large
figure.titleweight : normal
font.cursive : Apple Chancery, Textile , Zapf Chancery, Sand, Script MT, Felipa, cursive
font.family : Quicksand
font.fantasy : Comic Sans MS, Chicago, Charcoal, ImpactWestern, Humor Sans, xkcd, fantasy]
font.monospace : DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Computer Modern Typewriter, Andale Mono, Nimbus Mono L, Courier New, Courier, Fixed, Terminal, monospace
font.sans-serif : Arial, Liberation Sans, DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, sans-serif
font.serif : DejaVu Serif, Bitstream Vera Serif, Computer Modern Roman, New Century Schoolbook, Century Schoolbook L, Utopia, ITC Bookman, Bookman, Nimbus Roman No9 L, Times New Roman, Times, Palatino, Charter, serif
font.size : 10.0
font.stretch : normal
font.style : normal
font.variant : normal
font.weight : bold
grid.alpha : 1.0
grid.color : .8
grid.linestyle : -
grid.linewidth : 0.8
hatch.color : k
hatch.linewidth : 1.0
hist.bins : 10
image.aspect : equal
image.cmap : Greys
image.composite_image : True
image.interpolation : nearest
image.lut : 256
image.origin : upper
image.resample : True
keymap.all_axes : a
keymap.back : left, c, backspace
keymap.forward : right, v
keymap.fullscreen : f, ctrl+f
keymap.grid : g
keymap.grid_minor : G
keymap.home : h, r, home
keymap.pan : p
keymap.quit : ctrl+w, cmd+w, q
keymap.quit_all : W, cmd+W, Q
keymap.save : s, ctrl+s
keymap.xscale : k, L
keymap.yscale : l
keymap.zoom : o
legend.borderaxespad : 0.5
legend.borderpad : 0.4
legend.columnspacing : 2.0
legend.edgecolor : 0.8
legend.facecolor : inherit
legend.fancybox : True
legend.fontsize : medium
legend.framealpha : 0.8
legend.frameon : False
legend.handleheight : 0.7
legend.handlelength : 2.0
legend.handletextpad : 0.8
legend.labelspacing : 0.5
legend.loc : best
legend.markerscale : 1.0
legend.numpoints : 1
legend.scatterpoints : 1
legend.shadow : False
lines.antialiased : True
lines.color : C0
lines.dash_capstyle : butt
lines.dash_joinstyle : round
lines.dashdot_pattern : 6.4, 1.6, 1.0, 1.6
lines.dashed_pattern : 3.7, 1.6
lines.dotted_pattern : 1.0, 1.65
lines.linestyle : -
lines.linewidth : 1.5
lines.marker : None
lines.markeredgewidth : 1.0
lines.markersize : 50.0
lines.scale_dashes : True
lines.solid_capstyle : round
lines.solid_joinstyle : round
markers.fillstyle : full
mathtext.bf : sans:bold
mathtext.cal : cursive
mathtext.default : it
mathtext.fallback_to_cm : True
mathtext.fontset : dejavusans
mathtext.it : sans:italic
mathtext.rm : sans
mathtext.sf : sans
mathtext.tt : monospace
patch.antialiased : True
patch.edgecolor : k
patch.facecolor : C0
patch.force_edgecolor : False
patch.linewidth : 1.0
path.effects : None
path.simplify : True
path.simplify_threshold : 0.111111111111
path.sketch : None
path.snap : True
pdf.compression : 6
pdf.fonttype : 3
pdf.inheritcolor : False
pdf.use14corefonts : False
pgf.debug : False
pgf.preamble : []
pgf.rcfonts : True
pgf.texsystem : xelatex
polaraxes.grid : True
ps.distiller.res : 6000
ps.fonttype : 3
ps.papersize : letter
ps.useafm : False
ps.usedistiller : False
savefig.bbox : tight
savefig.dpi : figure
savefig.edgecolor : w
savefig.facecolor : w
savefig.format : png
savefig.frameon : True
savefig.jpeg_quality : 95
savefig.orientation : portrait
savefig.pad_inches : 0.1
savefig.transparent : False
scatter.marker : o
svg.fonttype : path
svg.hashsalt : None
svg.image_inline : True
text.antialiased : True
text.color : .15
text.hinting : auto
text.hinting_factor : 8
text.latex.preamble :
text.latex.preview : False
text.latex.unicode : False
text.usetex : False
verbose.fileo : sys.stdout
verbose.level : silent
xtick.alignment : center
xtick.bottom : True
xtick.color : .15
xtick.direction : out
xtick.major.bottom : True
xtick.major.pad : 3.5
xtick.major.size : 6.0
xtick.major.top : True
xtick.major.width : 0.8
xtick.minor.bottom : True
xtick.minor.pad : 3.4
xtick.minor.size : 3.0
xtick.minor.top : True
xtick.minor.visible : False
xtick.minor.width : 0.6
xtick.top : False
ytick.alignment : center_baseline
ytick.color : .15
ytick.direction : out
ytick.labelsize : medium
ytick.left : True
ytick.major.left : True
ytick.major.pad : 3.5
ytick.major.right : True
ytick.major.size : 6.0
ytick.major.width : 0.8
ytick.minor.left : True
ytick.minor.pad : 3.4
ytick.minor.right : True
ytick.minor.size : 3.0
ytick.minor.visible : False
ytick.minor.width : 0.6
ytick.right : False
```

and the error is:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    236 
    237     if 'png' in formats:
--> 238         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    239     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    240         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    120 
    121     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 122     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    123     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    124     if fmt == 'svg':

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2214                     orientation=orientation,
   2215                     dryrun=True,
-> 2216                     **kwargs)
   2217                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2218                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    505 
    506     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 507         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    508         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    509         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    428             # if toolbar:
    429             #     toolbar.set_cursor(cursors.WAIT)
--> 430             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    431         finally:
    432             # if toolbar:

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1294 
   1295             if self.frameon:
-> 1296                 self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1297 
   1298             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py in draw(self, renderer)
    542             renderer = PathEffectRenderer(self.get_path_effects(), renderer)
    543 
--> 544         renderer.draw_path(gc, tpath, affine, rgbFace)
    545 
    546         gc.restore()

~/miniconda3/envs/py36_anomaly_detection/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/patheffects.py in draw_path(self, gc, tpath, affine, rgbFace)
    107     def draw_path(self, gc, tpath, affine, rgbFace=None):
    108         for path_effect in self._path_effects:
--> 109             path_effect.draw_path(self._renderer, gc, tpath, affine,
    110                                   rgbFace)
    111 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'draw_path'<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7fb9268cefd0>81.1
```

I created the mplstyle file by printing `plt.rcParams` and then manually editing the output. Doing this created depreciated variables which had to be deleted and also needed conversions from lists to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace

```
path.effects : None
```

by

```
path.effects :
```

i.e. nothing behind the colon.

In general it seems your style file just has all the standard parameters in it. You can achieve the same by just using an empty file. 
If you want to change some of those, just add those that you wish to change to the file.